# Quickbooks sdk 13.0 (qbsdk130.exe)

Tags: authentication, sdk

Good morning

I have been trying, for 3 hours, to log-in to the Intuit pages to download the SDK version 13 but without any luck. 
https://developer.intuit.com/Downloads/Restricted?filename=qbsdk130.exe

Does anyone have the SDK file that they could send to me please or is anyone actually able to access the above page?

Thank you 
Simon

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, very frustrating.  To fix it I had to:

1. Login http://developer.intuit.com
2. Go to "My Apps"
3. "Create New App"
4. Sign up as an IPP Developer

Then the download link worked

Comment: I can't even get to the login page. You think they'd address this issue after 3 months.

Comment: Agh, finally.  Leave it to Intuit to mess something up as simple as a file download...

Comment: I ran into this problem today and this solution worked.  Note, it was counter intuitive because I wanted the 13.0 SDK for the Desktop but I had to create an App for the Online API So I created a "SampleApp".  This seemed to get me past that spinning dots window that prevented me from downloading the file.  Its probably worth noting that I probably already agreed to the service agreement some time ago that others are suggesting is popping up.  So you may have to do both things

Answer (score 0):

The file wouldn't download for me until I signed up as an Intuit Partner and also agreed to the terms of service.  I wasn't prompted to agree when I signed up or when I tried to download the file - instead the prompt showed up when I clicked on "My Apps" after signing in.

I reloaded the download page and the file downloaded.  Totally straightforward!  Way to go Intuit.

Answer (score 0):

Copying but Expanding on the Problem from daggerhart

1) Login http://developer.intuit.com
2) Go to "My Apps"
3) "Create New App"

Note:  This is counter-intuitive because as of the date of this post, the Create New App, creates an "Online App" but the SDK 13.0 is a Desktop Product. So you're wondering why is this necessary.

But once the Online App is created then the download linked worked.

I do also want to note, that at this point, I had already created a developer account AND agreed to the necessary releases that are required.  There are few fragmented postings that suggest this to be partially the issue.  Probably in earlier versions of the problem since this problem is over 6 years old and apparently its still live and kicking. Kudos to the intuit team... but hey, you only have the problem once.